# Using datetime to evaluate if a given time is already in the past

Tags: python, datetime

This is my current code:

```
import requests
import json

res = requests.get("http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections? 
from=Baldegg_kloster&to=Luzern&fields[]=connections/from/prognosis/departure")

parsed_json = res.json()

time_1 = parsed_json['connections'][0]['from']['prognosis']
time_2 = parsed_json['connections'][1]['from']['prognosis']
time_3 = parsed_json['connections'][2]['from']['prognosis']
```

The JSON data looks like this:

```
{
    "connections": [
        {"from": {"prognosis": {"departure": "2018-08-04T14:21:00+0200"}}},
        {"from": {"prognosis": {"departure": "2018-08-04T14:53:00+0200"}}},
        {"from": {"prognosis": {"departure": "2018-08-04T15:22:00+0200"}}},
        {"from": {"prognosis": {"departure": "2018-08-04T15:53:00+0200"}}}
    ]
}
```

Time_1, 2 and 3 all contain different times where the train departs. I want to check if time_1 is already in the past, and time_2 now is the relevant time. In my opinion, using datetime.now to get the current time and then using If / elif to check if time_1 is sooner than datetime.now would be a viable option. I am new to coding, so I am unsure if this is a good way of doing it. Would this work and are there any better ways?

PS: I am planning to make a display that displays the time the next train leaves. Therefore, it would have to check if the time is still relevant over and over again.

Comment: How is the time formatted? Could you add some input examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code extracts all the departure time strings from the JSON data, and converts the valid time strings to datetime objects. It then prints the current time, and then a list of the departure times that are still in the future.

Sometimes the converted JSON has `None` for a departure time, so we need to deal with that. And we need to get the current time as a timezone-aware object. We *could* just use the UTC timezone, but it's more convenient to use the local timezone from the JSON data.

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
import requests

url = "http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections? from=Baldegg_kloster&to=Luzern&fields[]=connections/from/prognosis/departure"
res = requests.get(url)
parsed_json = res.json()

# Extract all the departure time strings from the JSON data
time_strings = [d["from"]["prognosis"]["departure"]
    for d in parsed_json["connections"]]
#print(time_strings)

# The format string to parse ISO 8601 date + time strings 
iso_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"

# Convert the valid time strings to datetime objects 
times = [datetime.strptime(ts, iso_format) 
    for ts in time_strings if ts is not None]

# Grab the timezone info from the first time
tz = times[0].tzinfo
# The current time, using the same timezone
nowtime = datetime.now(tz)
# Get rid of the microseconds
nowtime = nowtime.replace(microsecond=0)
print('Now', nowtime)

# Print the times that are still in the future
for i, t in enumerate(times):
    if t > nowtime:
        diff = t - nowtime
        print('{}.  {} departing in {}'.format(i, t, diff))
```

**output**

```
Now 2018-08-04 17:17:25+02:00
1.  2018-08-04 17:22:00+02:00 departing in 0:04:35
2.  2018-08-04 17:53:00+02:00 departing in 0:35:35
3.  2018-08-04 18:22:00+02:00 departing in 1:04:35
```

---

That query URL is a bit ugly, and not convenient if you want to check on other stations. It's better to let `requests` build the query URL for you from a dictionary of parameters. And we should also check that the request was successful, which we can do with the [`raise_for_status`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) method.

Just replace the top section of the script with this:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
import requests

endpoint = "http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections"

params = {
    "from": "Baldegg_kloster",
    "to": "Luzern",
    "fields[]": "connections/from/prognosis/departure",
}

res = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)
res.raise_for_status()
parsed_json = res.json()
```

---

If you've never used [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) before, it can be a little confusing at first. Here's a brief demo of three different ways to loop over a list of items and print each item and its index number.

```
things = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']
for i, word in enumerate(things):
    print(i, word)

for i in range(len(things)):
    word = things[i]
    print(i, word)

i = 0
while i < len(things):
    word = things[i]
    print(i, word)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice and clean answer, it really helped me a lot! However, I still have a question: What do i and t stand for in the For Loop? I changed i to a and t to b and it still worked. Now I'm confused on how the programme knows what i and t stand for.

Comment: @DominikSidler We can use any names we like, I just used `i` for index, because that's a common practice, and I used `t` to stand for `time`. I guess I should have used a more meaningful name, like `departure_time`, but I'm lazy. ;) You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused: How does the program know that `i` stands for Index and `t` for time? Because I thought you had to define them as you define `x = 25`

Comment: @DominikSidler Well, the program doesn't really "know" that `i` stands for Index. On each round through the `for` loop, `enumerate(times)` produces an `(index, value)` pair, (where `value` is the next item from the `times` list), and the `for i, t in ...` syntax says to assign that pair to `i` and `t`.

Comment: @DominikSidler I'll add a little bit of demo code to the end of my answer that compares looping with and without `enumerate`.

Comment: I understand it now, thanks to your explanations. The additional demo code was really useful!

Comment: Is there a way I can ask you another Question related to this one? Asking in this comment thread is not possible because the Code sample is too big, and editing the Question could confuse other People

Comment: @DominikSidler Just ask a fresh question. You can explain in the new question that it's related to this one, and include a link, if you think it will be helpful to people reading it. You can put a link to your new question here in this comment thread, but I may not have time to look at or work on your question for several hours.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question properly. I think you are trying to compare two time.

First let's see the contents of `time_1`:

`{'departure': '2018-08-04T15:24:00+0200'}`

So add `departure` key to access time. To parse the date and time string to python understandable time we use `datetime.strptime()` method. See this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for further description on `datatime.strptime()`

The modified version of your code that does time comparision:

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime

res = requests.get("http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections? from=Baldegg_kloster&to=Luzern&fields[]=connections/from/prognosis/departure")

parsed_json = res.json()

time_1 = parsed_json['connections'][0]['from']['prognosis']['departure']
time_2 = parsed_json['connections'][1]['from']['prognosis']['departure']
time_3 = parsed_json['connections'][2]['from']['prognosis']['departure']

mod_time_1 = datetime.strptime(time_1,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
mod_time_2 = datetime.strptime(time_2,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')

# you need to provide datetime.now() your timezone.
timezone = mod_time_1.tzinfo
time_now = datetime.now(timezone)
print(time_now > mod_time_1)
```